# How to format SQL subquery to produce new and old data

Tags: sql

I have a database where I am trying to figure out this problem. I want to write a SQL query to list all patients whose information has changed during their future visits. A future visit is defined as dbo.patientvisit.encounter_id < dbo.visitvitalstat.encounter_id The outputs I want in the table are the columns patient number, old and new race values, old and new gender values, and both encounter ids from the both tables. The new race and gender values are from future visits.

[image] [image]

This is the code I have so far but I can't figure out how to get the new gender and new race values.

```
SELECT pv.patient_nbr,pv.encounter_id, vvs.race, vvs.gender, vvs.encounter_id
FROM PatientVisit pv
LEFT JOIN VisitVitalStat vvs
ON pv.encounter_id = vvs.encounter_id
WHERE pv.encounter_id < vvs.encounter_id;
```

This is the result I should get back:
[image]

```
SELECT  fpv.patient_nbr(??)
                vvs.race as "Old race",
                fv.newrace as "New Race",
                vvs.gender as "Old Gender",
                fv.newgender as " New Gender",
                vvs.encounter_id as "Old Encounter ID" ,
                fv.newencounter as "New Encounter ID"
FROM  VisitVitalStat vvs
INNER JOIN
                    ( SELECT fpv.patient_nbr as newnbr,
                                      fvvs.race as newrace,
                                      fvvs.gender as newgender,
                                      fvvs.encounter_id as newencounter
FROM PatientVisit fpv, VisitVitalStat fvvs
                      WHERE  fpv.encounter_id = fvvs.encounter_id
                              AND
                                      fpv.encounter_id < fvvs.encounter_id) fv
ON   fv.newencounter = vvs.encounter_id;
```

So I was able to write a query but I feel like it is still off, I'm not sure how to get patient number into all of this.

Comment: there is a contradiction in your join with your where.
```sql
LEFT JOIN VisitVitalStat vvs
ON pv.encounter_id = vvs.encounter_id
WHERE pv.encounter_id < vvs.encounter_id
```
You should have another for the join like
LEFT JOIN VisitVitalStat vvs
ON pv.patient_nbr = vvs.patient_nbr

Comment: Can you please write one query for adding another join? I can’t seem to understand still

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag are all helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt this solution. Where b1 will be the old data and b2 the new data.

```sql
with base as (
    select
        patient_nbr
        ,encounter_id
        ,row_number() over (partition by patient_nbr order by encounter_id asc) as row
    from patientvisit
    LEFT JOIN VisitVitalStat vvs
    ON pv.encounter_id = vvs.encounter_id

)
select b1.patient_nbr
    ,b1.encounter_id as old
    ,b2.encounter_id as new
    ,b1.gender as old
    ,b2.gender as new
    ,b1.race as old
    ,b2.race as new
from base b1
join base b2 on
    b1.patient_nbr=b2.patient_nbr
    and b1.row+1=b2.row
```

Comment: I still need the genders and age both old and new. Where can I fit that in this with the table visitvitalstat?

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `lag()`:

```
select pv.*
from (select pv.*,
             lag(gender) over (partition by patient_nbr order by encounter) as prev_gender,
             lag(race) over (partition by patient_nbr order by encounter) as prev_race,
             lag(encounter) over (partition by patient_nbr order by encounter) as prev_encounter
      from patientvisit pv
     ) pv
where prev_gender <> gender or prev_race <> race;
```

Comment: Is there a way to get to a similar code that I wrote or using a subquery? The code you wrote seems off since gender and race are in the visitvitalstat table not the patientvisit table.